# How to link to current post in WordPress?

Tags: permalinks, shortcode

I'd need to get a permalink for *this post* (current post) in WordPress. Easy to do in PHP but I'd need to use it in the article itself so no PHP? I'd need a button that links to the current article. While this may sound silly, there's a reason for it but too hard to explain. :D How to proceed? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the type of scenario shortcodes are intended for. Simply add the following to your theme's functions file to create the shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'this_permalink', 'this_permalink' );

function this_permalink($atts, $content){
   return '<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">Link to this article</a>';
}
```

.. and use this in your post to render the link:

```
[this_permalink]
```

I cannot think though, why you would want to link to a current article, but I guess you have your reasons :)

Comment: A simple and elegant solution. To make it easy to style it like a Button, you could add a class declaration to the shortcode so something like '<a class="button" href="....." then be sure you have some button styles setup in your CSS.